# Android InAppBrowser virtual keyboard closes on executeScript(). [phonegap]

Tags: android, cordova

I copied my code from the following link. It's a workaround for Passing Data From an InAppBrowser back to the app.

blogs.telerik.com/appbuilder/posts/13-12-23/cross-window-communication-with-cordova's-inappbrowser

The problem is that after each executescript() the Keyboard disappears.

This issue status here is "won't fix". So I'm wondering if there is an alternative solution. I only see a reference to KitKat users, but that would only represent a limited amount.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-5449

Suggestions?

```
    setName: function() {
        var win = window.open( "http://jsfiddle.net/tj_vantoll/K2yqc/show", "_blank",
          "EnableViewPortScale=yes" );

        win.addEventListener( "loadstop", function() {
            win.executeScript({ code: "localStorage.setItem( 'name', '' );" });
            var loop = setInterval(function() {
                win.executeScript(
                    {
                        code: "localStorage.getItem( 'name' )"
                    },
                    function( values ) {
                        var name = values[ 0 ];
                        if ( name ) {
                            clearInterval( loop );
                            win.close();
                            $( "h1" ).html( "Welcome " + name + "!" );
                        }
                    }
                );
            });
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your use case, it might be a feasible workaround to check if the keyboard is currently visible and avoid calling `executeScript` in that case.

Try using the [com.ionic.keyboard](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-plugins-keyboard) plugin to get `cordova.plugins.Keyboard.isVisible` and use that in your `setInterval` function.

Comment: There are also `showkeyboard`/`hidekeyboard` events provided by core Cordova, but they seemed to be less reliable. They were e.g. triggered when rotating the device, which lead to false positives during my tests.

Comment: Thanks Gregor. I'll investigate your solutions.